# Decode BSON stream to human-readable string

Tags: c#, json.net, bson

I'm writing a C# tool which retrieves and aggregates some data from an Oracle DB and displays it in a clean and readable format.
I came across this VARCHAR column, which contains a BSON stream. I'd like to decode to something human-readable (JSON should do the job).
I'm trying to use [Newtonsoft.Json.Bson](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Bson) to de-serialize this stream. I'm using the following code:

```
byte[] rawData = new byte[] { 226, 6, 0, 0, 3, 68, 101, 102, 97, 117, 108, 116, 82, 101, 118, 101, 114, 115, 101, 82, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 52, 73, 84, 84, 73, 0, 193, 6, 0, 0, 3, 111, 114, 100, 101, 114, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 115, 0, 175, 6, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 108, 105, 115, 116, 0, 144, 6, 0, 0, 0, 144, 6, 0, 0, 4, 108, 105, 115, 116, 0, 133, 6, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 51, 51, 52, 49, 50, 56, 52, 52, 57, 52, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 77, 83, 73, 83, 68, 78, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 163, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 136, 0, 0, 0, 0, 136, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 65, 0, 0, 0, 51, 55, 56, 50, 122, 85, 68, 68, 89, 67, 56, 57, 114, 104, 99, 76, 78, 57, 48, 101, 71, 56, 74, 113, 52, 122, 66, 75, 87, 97, 119, 50, 69, 69, 67, 120, 106, 105, 57, 118, 115, 110, 103, 86, 117, 79, 86, 73, 71, 77, 88, 106, 48, 77, 79, 53, 120, 83, 55, 65, 84, 50, 114, 56, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 83, 101, 113, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 79, 112, 67, 111, 100, 101, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 67, 95, 79, 80, 69, 82, 65, 84, 73, 79, 78, 95, 67, 79, 68, 69, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 115, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 79, 112, 82, 101, 97, 115, 111, 110, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 67, 95, 79, 80, 69, 82, 65, 84, 73, 79, 78, 95, 82, 69, 65, 83, 79, 78, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 116, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 67, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 83, 117, 98, 83, 121, 115, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 67, 95, 67, 76, 73, 69, 78, 84, 95, 83, 85, 66, 83, 89, 83, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 125, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 67, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 70, 105, 110, 73, 110, 102, 111, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 67, 95, 67, 76, 73, 69, 78, 84, 95, 70, 73, 78, 65, 78, 67, 73, 65, 76, 95, 73, 78, 70, 79, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 117, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 50, 48, 49, 56, 49, 50, 50, 56, 49, 53, 51, 57, 50, 50, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 79, 80, 69, 82, 65, 84, 73, 79, 78, 95, 68, 65, 84, 69, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 108, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 50, 48, 49, 51, 51, 52, 49, 50, 56, 52, 52, 57, 52, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 73, 77, 83, 73, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 95, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 68, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 51, 56, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 80, 82, 79, 70, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 94, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 84, 89, 80, 69, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 93, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 48, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 68, 79, 77, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 94, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 83, 86, 73, 83, 0, 0, 0, 3, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 107, 0, 0, 0, 5, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 2, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 101, 120, 116, 121, 112, 101, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 87, 79, 67, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 79, 98, 106, 80, 97, 114, 97, 109, 0, 2, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 79, 75, 73, 68, 83, 0, 2, 99, 111, 100, 101, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 79, 70, 70, 69, 82, 73, 78, 71, 95, 67, 79, 68, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(rawData);
using (BsonDataReader bsonDataReader = new BsonDataReader(memoryStream))
{
    JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    String test = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(bsonDataReader).ToString();
}
```

(byte array brutally initialized for the sake of brevity)
Executing this code produces the following output in the "test" variable:

```
{
  "DefaultReverseRequest4ITTI": {
    "orderParams": {
      "complexpropertylist": "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"
    }
  }
}
```

From my understanding, this is happening because the "complexpropertylist" field contains a byte array itself (maybe base64-encoded?).
So, how can I tell the de-serializer to recursively process every child node?

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: There's no way to do this automagically, AFAIK. I think you're going to have to write a custom `JsonConverter` that does this.

Comment: By any chance, do you know any article or documentation about doing that? I'm totally new to this library

Comment: What is the expected output if everything worked the way you wanted it to?

Answer (score 0):

With the MongoDB.Bson nuget package you can use the following:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

TestType testObj = new("abc");

// Serialization
byte[] testObjAsBsonArray = testObj.ToBson();
// Set nominal type to object. If the nominal type differs from the actual type then type information is included in the bson.
byte[] testObjAsBsonArrayWithTypeInfo = testObj.ToBson<object>();
string testObjAsJsonString = testObj.ToJson();
BsonDocument testObjAsBsonDocument = testObj.ToBsonDocument();

// Deserialization
TestType fromArray = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestType>(testObjAsBsonArray);
// fromArrayWithTypeInfo.GetType() equals typeof(TestType)
object fromArrayWithTypeInfo = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(testObjAsBsonArrayWithTypeInfo);
TestType fromJson = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestType>(testObjAsJsonString);
TestType fromBsonDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestType>(testObjAsBsonDocument);

public record TestType(string TestValue);
```